# Таблица с выводом данных на пересечении строк и столбцов

Tags: php, html, веб-программирование

Как можно сделать таблицу такого вида?
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

1 - 5 - названия файлов, на пересечении (т. е . 2 пересекается с 4 и наоборот, к примеру) выводятся данные о проценте совпадений двух файлов.
Как и чем это лучше реализовать?

Comment: Во-первых нижнюю строку `1-5` надо переместить как у людей - вверх )  А остальное - это просто два цикла - один в другом